# Pin one child in center with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to align the "child--featured" of each "parent" to the center of "container" class with flexbox.

This is what I have right now:

[image: Wrong]

And this is the desired output:

[image: Correct layout]

Is this possible?

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  border-color: #3B8686;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.child {
  background-color: #79BD9A;
  border-color: #CFF09E;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0.1em
}

.child--featured {
  background-color: #3B8686;
}

.parent.one .child {
  width: 3em
}

.parent.one .child:nth-child(1) {
  width: 8em
}

.parent.one .child:nth-child(4) {
  width: 6em
}

.parent.two .child {
  width: 4em;
}

.parent.two .child:nth-child(1) {
  width: 1em
}

.parent.two .child:nth-child(2) {
  width: 5em
}

.parent.two .child:nth-child(3) {
  width: 6em
}

.parent.two .child:nth-child(4) {
  width: 5em
}

.parent.three .child {
  width: 2em
}

.parent.three .child:nth-child(4) {
  width: 5em
}

.parent.three .child:nth-child(3) {
  width: 2em
}

.parent.three .child:nth-child(2) {
  width: 10em
}

.parent.three .child:nth-child(1) {
  width: 10em
}

.rule {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <p class="rule"></p>

  <div class="parent one">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child child--featured">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent two">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child child--featured">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent three">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child child--featured">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/harmeetjaipur/pen/aPaWKL)

Comment: Without those images this question is quite difficult to explain. I'm trying to figure out how to write the question without images. Damn, I was just about to leave my pc for the night.

Comment: *How to align various rows of differing lengths to the center of the container, anchored by a specified element in each row?*

Comment: That's better than mine.

Comment: Might explain the question, but will never be found via search. LOL. In terms of a solution, not sure it's possible with CSS alone, unless you know in advance the length of each row and the position of `child--featured`. Then you can just use css positioning to align the row.

Comment: Length is fixed, 5 children always.

Comment: Always the third child that will be the featured (or anchored) as well.

Comment: Then you need to know the position of "3" in the row, so you can determine the offset value of `position`.

Comment: Like I said, CSS may not be your best option here. There's likely a cleaner and more efficient JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Yes, This is possible. I have tried this and my head is out. But  I have done this. You can like this:

```
.parent.one {
     margin-left: -30px;
}
.parent.two {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.parent.three {
    margin-left: -200px;
}
```

Comment: I can't have fixed values for margins as these rows will be generated dynamically with varying widths for each child.

Comment: So, I can't do this with other way :(

Comment: That's ok. Thanks for the effort. :)